# I am designing a 2 resistor MOSFET amplifier but the output is generating square waves

Tags: mosfet, amplifier, ltspice

[image: The circuit]

[image: The simulation]

I am learning about MOSFETs and I was tasked to design a 2 resistor biased amplifier. This is what I came up with. I am really not sure what a 2 resistor biased amplifier is, could someone please help me out?

Why is the circuit that I have attached giving me square waves as the output? If I reduce the amplitude of V1, the output is a straight line.

Comment: What did you intend for the gain? Because right now the output is quickly alternating between deep cutoff and deep saturation.

Comment: Try significantly decreasing the input amplitude.

Comment: @Reinderien I did but then the simulation shows a flat line. I tried moving from 3.3V to 2V

Comment: Consider that sine wave is +/- with respect to GND... that looks a bit weird to me looking at the circuit

Comment: @Reinderien just wanted to have enough gain to prevent clipping, since I am still learning about MOSFETS I have no idea how to choose the values for this circuit.

Comment: @vicatcu meaning?

Comment: The simulation shows a flat line because you have the wrong bias. Change your input to a ramp from 0 to Vdd to see the effective threshold.

Comment: Then make a DC bias divider for that voltage and add a decoupling cap to your input.

Comment: @Reinderien How do I choose the value for the decoupling Cap?

Comment: Get the time constant needed to allow the minimum possible input frequency, whatever that is

Comment: @Reinderien Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Try putting a resistor between source and ground:

[image]

Play with the ratio between R3 and R2 to adjust gain and with the DC offset on V1 for input range to get a feel for how the MOSFET works.  Notice that your output is inverted.

Good luck!